# Adding block style dependencies

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I'm running into a problem where my block styles are being enqueued before my theme style. Because of this, the theme style is overriding my blocks and that is undesirable.

Is it possible to add style dependencies from within a gutenberg block (ideally in the block.json). My goal is to load the block styles AFTER my theme stylesheet.